# Strong vs strongly

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

''We started strong...''

''We started strongly...''

Which one is correct? I thought that ''started'' required an adverb, but I've recently heard someone say ''strong'' and now I have this conundrum.

Answer (score 4):

They are both possible but mean different things.

> We started strong...

This means that when we started, *we* were strong.

Example

We got lost in the mountains and had to walk for days. We started strong but after two days without food we became weak.

> We started strongly...

This means that we started in a strong way.

Example

When the match began we got a goal within the first five minutes. We started strongly. By the end of the match we were physically exhausted but so were our opponents so we still managed to finish strongly and scored again just before the whistle.

Comment: I agree but would add that "started strong" is more idiomatic, possibly for both meanings, especially in spoken speech.